# A.P. problem involving sum and product

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Problem:

> Let $a_i , i \in \lbrace {1,2,3,4,5} \rbrace$ represent $5$ terms in A.P. with common difference greater than $2$. If $\sum_{i=1}^5 a_i=30$ and $\Pi_{i=1}^5 a_i=3840$, find $a_1\cdot a_5$

I took the most obvious route-writing all $a_i s$ in terms of $d$ and headed to solve the bi-quadratic equation. $d$ gets us the answer.

However, I think there is a more elegant way of solving this(also supported by the fact that the question doesn't want us to evaluate $d$ directly). I couldn't find one. Can you help?

Comment: It's just a quadratic equation, really.  Writing your progression as $\{a_3-2P, a_3-P, a_3, a_3+P,a_3+2P\}$ we quickly see that $a_3=6$ and that $P$ is a root of $6(6^2-P^2)(6^2-4P^2)=3840$, which is a quadratic equation in $x=P^2$.

Comment: I know it is reducible to quadratic. However I'm not convinced that it is the simplest one

Comment: The fact that the answer is $P= \sqrt {41}$ tends to suggest that any answer at all is going to require some algebra, and this method is very straight forward.  But, of course, it's possible that there is some other line of attack.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_1a_5=x$. Then

$$5 (\frac{a_1+a_5}{2})=30 \implies a_1+a_5=12$$
$$a_3=\frac{a_1+a_5}{2}=6$$
$$a_2a_4=(\frac{a_1+a_3}{2})(\frac{a_3+a_5}{2})=\frac14(a_1+6)(6+a_5)=\frac14 (a_1a_5+6[a_1+a_5]+36)=\frac14(x+108)$$

$$a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5=(a_3)(a_1a_5)(a_2a_4)=\frac64 x(x+108)=3840$$

$$x^2+108x-2560=(x+128)(x-20)=0$$ $$x=+20, -128$$

Since $a_1+a_5=2a_1+4d=12$ and $d\gt 2$ then $a_1 \lt 0$ and $a_5 \gt 0$ so $a_1a_5 \lt 0$. Therefore $$a_1a_5=x=-128$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the first equality?

Comment: @DatBoi Sum of terms of AP = no. of terms  x average of 1st and last terms.